# Programatically adding MenuItems triggers Page_load in target URL

Tags: asp.net, menuitem

I am adding menu items programmatically so I can control which ones appear based on the role of the user. My problem is that every menu item I add behaves as if it has been clicked on during the load.  Stripped to bare bones, here is the simplified code:

```
Public Class test2
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Private Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        CreateMenu()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub CreateMenu()
    MainMenu.Items.Add(New MenuItem("Home", "", "/Peak.aspx"))
End Sub
End Class
```

The test2.aspx contains:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Menu ID="MainMenu" runat="server" >
        <Items>
        </Items>
    </asp:Menu>
</form>
```

This is all the code in Peak.aspx.vb:

```
Public Class Peak
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
                System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        MsgBox("This should not appear but does!!")
    End Sub

End Class
```

The Peak.aspx Page_Load is being loaded and the message box displayed, when test2 is set as the start up page.  My real code has several menu items added and CreateMenu causes ALL the page_Loads to be being triggered with a large overhead!

Is this a bug or something I can switch off, and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using this constructor https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b00a9c35.aspx

```
public MenuItem(
    string text,
    string value,
    string imageUrl
)
```

If you look at it carefully, your third parameter sets imageurl, thus triggering Page_Load event when it tries to load the url. Maybe you wanted to use this overload with 4 parameters? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70k2h50z.aspx

```
public MenuItem(
    string text,
    string value,
    string imageUrl,
    string navigateUrl
)
```

Comment: Thank you!! Somehow I missed seeing 'value' when reading the intellisense and thought the middle one was imageURL.  So simple!!  The most annoying problems always turn out to be the most obvious.  (Sorry it won't let me vote up your answer as I haven't been around long enough.)

Comment: @JoG, yeah, it happens to everyone from time to time. Welcome to this site by the way. Just a hint: if the answer solved your problem,  it's a good practice here to upvote/accept the answer for future reference for other readers who might stumble upon a similar problem. If it doesn't let you, no problem you can revisit later.

Comment: Ok I'll try again another time. Apparently I have to earn more points or something.

Comment: @JoG, you need at least 15 points to be able to vote up http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges . However, I do believe you should be able to accept the answer using the checkmark under the answer score even now, but I might be wrong.